# Visual studio for Mac missing Toolbox items

Tags: macos, visual-studio, toolbox, visual-studio-mac

Hi I've just installed Visual Studio for Mac. I've created a new solution/project (ASP.NET Core Empty Web Application), but for some reason I'm missing drag/drop items from the Toolbox. Any suggestions why its empty?

[image: IDE screenshot]

Thanks :)

Comment: I see I'm not alone. I'm trying to dev a mobile app. Both Forms (multiplatform) and the single-view template (Android) don't have a toolbox

Comment: I think there should be "code view" which only shows the codes and "design view" which allow you to do drag and drop?

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me too. I installed the latest updates, closed VS and re-opened it. Suddenly the tools were there.